# fresh install of bazel fails to build grpc 1.48.0?

Tags: c++, cmake, grpc, bazel, grpc-c++

Im brand new to both grpc and bazel, but wanting to give it a try in C++ to see if it can work for replacing thrift which is getting longer in the tooth with each C++ release.

```
$ gcc --version
gcc (Ubuntu 11.2.0-19ubuntu1) 11.2.0
Copyright (C) 2021 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.

$ bazel --version
INFO: Running bazel wrapper (see //tools/bazel for details), bazel version 4.2.1 will be used instead of system-wide bazel installation.
bazel 4.2.1
```

https://github.com/grpc/grpc/blob/master/BUILDING.md#linux

when I run though I get errors about the automatic c++ toolchain.. I've installed all the apt packages mentioned but now lost as to why it cannot see gcc

```
bazel build :all
INFO: Running bazel wrapper (see //tools/bazel for details), bazel version 4.2.1 will be used instead of system-wide bazel installation.
DEBUG: /home/emcp/.cache/bazel/_bazel_emcp/281ba5a21da7173aa4ab26dbe66e8d65/external/bazel_toolchains/rules/rbe_repo/version_check.bzl:68:14: 
Current running Bazel is ahead of bazel-toolchains repo. Please update your pin to bazel-toolchains repo in your WORKSPACE file.
DEBUG: /home/emcp/.cache/bazel/_bazel_emcp/281ba5a21da7173aa4ab26dbe66e8d65/external/bazel_toolchains/rules/rbe_repo/checked_in.bzl:125:14: rbe_default not using checked in configs; Bazel version 4.2.1 was picked/selected but no checked in config was found in map {"0.20.0": ["8.0.0"], "0.21.0": ["8.0.0"], "0.22.0": ["8.0.0", "9.0.0"], "0.23.0": ["8.0.0", "9.0.0"], "0.23.1": ["8.0.0", "9.0.0"], "0.23.2": ["9.0.0"], "0.24.0": ["9.0.0"], "0.24.1": ["9.0.0"], "0.25.0": ["9.0.0"], "0.25.1": ["9.0.0"], "0.25.2": ["9.0.0"], "0.26.0": ["9.0.0"], "0.26.1": ["9.0.0"], "0.27.0": ["9.0.0"], "0.27.1": ["9.0.0"], "0.28.0": ["9.0.0"], "0.28.1": ["9.0.0"], "0.29.0": ["9.0.0"], "0.29.1": ["9.0.0", "10.0.0"], "1.0.0": ["9.0.0", "10.0.0"], "1.0.1": ["10.0.0"], "1.1.0": ["10.0.0"], "1.2.0": ["10.0.0"], "1.2.1": ["10.0.0"], "2.0.0": ["10.0.0"], "2.1.0": ["10.0.0"], "2.1.1": ["10.0.0", "11.0.0"], "2.2.0": ["11.0.0"], "3.0.0": ["11.0.0"], "3.1.0": ["11.0.0"], "3.2.0": ["11.0.0"], "3.3.0": ["11.0.0"], "3.3.1": ["11.0.0"], "3.4.1": ["11.0.0"], "3.5.0": ["11.0.0"], "3.5.1": ["11.0.0"], "3.6.0": ["11.0.0"], "3.7.0": ["11.0.0"], "3.7.1": ["11.0.0"], "3.7.2": ["11.0.0"], "4.0.0": ["11.0.0"]}
DEBUG: /home/emcp/.cache/bazel/_bazel_emcp/281ba5a21da7173aa4ab26dbe66e8d65/external/bazel_toolchains/rules/rbe_repo/version_check.bzl:68:14: 
Current running Bazel is ahead of bazel-toolchains repo. Please update your pin to bazel-toolchains repo in your WORKSPACE file.
DEBUG: /home/emcp/.cache/bazel/_bazel_emcp/281ba5a21da7173aa4ab26dbe66e8d65/external/bazel_toolchains/rules/rbe_repo/checked_in.bzl:125:14: rbe_msan not using checked in configs; Bazel version 4.2.1 was picked/selected but no checked in config was found in map {"0.20.0": ["8.0.0"], "0.21.0": ["8.0.0"], "0.22.0": ["8.0.0", "9.0.0"], "0.23.0": ["8.0.0", "9.0.0"], "0.23.1": ["8.0.0", "9.0.0"], "0.23.2": ["9.0.0"], "0.24.0": ["9.0.0"], "0.24.1": ["9.0.0"], "0.25.0": ["9.0.0"], "0.25.1": ["9.0.0"], "0.25.2": ["9.0.0"], "0.26.0": ["9.0.0"], "0.26.1": ["9.0.0"], "0.27.0": ["9.0.0"], "0.27.1": ["9.0.0"], "0.28.0": ["9.0.0"], "0.28.1": ["9.0.0"], "0.29.0": ["9.0.0"], "0.29.1": ["9.0.0", "10.0.0"], "1.0.0": ["9.0.0", "10.0.0"], "1.0.1": ["10.0.0"], "1.1.0": ["10.0.0"], "1.2.0": ["10.0.0"], "1.2.1": ["10.0.0"], "2.0.0": ["10.0.0"], "2.1.0": ["10.0.0"], "2.1.1": ["10.0.0", "11.0.0"], "2.2.0": ["11.0.0"], "3.0.0": ["11.0.0"], "3.1.0": ["11.0.0"], "3.2.0": ["11.0.0"], "3.3.0": ["11.0.0"], "3.3.1": ["11.0.0"], "3.4.1": ["11.0.0"], "3.5.0": ["11.0.0"], "3.5.1": ["11.0.0"], "3.6.0": ["11.0.0"], "3.7.0": ["11.0.0"], "3.7.1": ["11.0.0"], "3.7.2": ["11.0.0"], "4.0.0": ["11.0.0"]}
INFO: Repository local_config_cc instantiated at:
  /DEFAULT.WORKSPACE.SUFFIX:368:13: in <toplevel>
  /home/emcp/.cache/bazel/_bazel_emcp/281ba5a21da7173aa4ab26dbe66e8d65/external/bazel_tools/tools/cpp/cc_configure.bzl:184:16: in cc_configure
Repository rule cc_autoconf defined at:
  /home/emcp/.cache/bazel/_bazel_emcp/281ba5a21da7173aa4ab26dbe66e8d65/external/bazel_tools/tools/cpp/cc_configure.bzl:145:30: in <toplevel>
ERROR: An error occurred during the fetch of repository 'local_config_cc':
   Traceback (most recent call last):
        File "/home/emcp/.cache/bazel/_bazel_emcp/281ba5a21da7173aa4ab26dbe66e8d65/external/bazel_tools/tools/cpp/cc_configure.bzl", line 127, column 33, in cc_autoconf_impl
                configure_unix_toolchain(repository_ctx, cpu_value, overriden_tools)
        File "/home/emcp/.cache/bazel/_bazel_emcp/281ba5a21da7173aa4ab26dbe66e8d65/external/bazel_tools/tools/cpp/unix_cc_configure.bzl", line 340, column 23, in configure_unix_toolchain
                cc = _find_generic(repository_ctx, "gcc", "CC", overriden_tools)
        File "/home/emcp/.cache/bazel/_bazel_emcp/281ba5a21da7173aa4ab26dbe66e8d65/external/bazel_tools/tools/cpp/unix_cc_configure.bzl", line 310, column 32, in _find_generic
                auto_configure_fail(msg)
        File "/home/emcp/.cache/bazel/_bazel_emcp/281ba5a21da7173aa4ab26dbe66e8d65/external/bazel_tools/tools/cpp/lib_cc_configure.bzl", line 112, column 9, in auto_configure_fail
                fail("\n%sAuto-Configuration Error:%s %s\n" % (red, no_color, msg))
Error in fail: 
Auto-Configuration Error: Cannot find gcc or CC (clang); either correct your path or set the CC environment variable
ERROR: Error fetching repository: Traceback (most recent call last):
        File "/home/emcp/.cache/bazel/_bazel_emcp/281ba5a21da7173aa4ab26dbe66e8d65/external/bazel_tools/tools/cpp/cc_configure.bzl", line 127, column 33, in cc_autoconf_impl
                configure_unix_toolchain(repository_ctx, cpu_value, overriden_tools)
        File "/home/emcp/.cache/bazel/_bazel_emcp/281ba5a21da7173aa4ab26dbe66e8d65/external/bazel_tools/tools/cpp/unix_cc_configure.bzl", line 340, column 23, in configure_unix_toolchain
                cc = _find_generic(repository_ctx, "gcc", "CC", overriden_tools)
        File "/home/emcp/.cache/bazel/_bazel_emcp/281ba5a21da7173aa4ab26dbe66e8d65/external/bazel_tools/tools/cpp/unix_cc_configure.bzl", line 310, column 32, in _find_generic
                auto_configure_fail(msg)
        File "/home/emcp/.cache/bazel/_bazel_emcp/281ba5a21da7173aa4ab26dbe66e8d65/external/bazel_tools/tools/cpp/lib_cc_configure.bzl", line 112, column 9, in auto_configure_fail
                fail("\n%sAuto-Configuration Error:%s %s\n" % (red, no_color, msg))
Error in fail: 
Auto-Configuration Error: Cannot find gcc or CC (clang); either correct your path or set the CC environment variable
INFO: Repository com_google_absl instantiated at:
  /home/emcp/Dev/git/grpc/grpc/WORKSPACE:5:10: in <toplevel>
  /home/emcp/Dev/git/grpc/grpc/bazel/grpc_deps.bzl:295:21: in grpc_deps
Repository rule http_archive defined at:
  /home/emcp/.cache/bazel/_bazel_emcp/281ba5a21da7173aa4ab26dbe66e8d65/external/bazel_tools/tools/build_defs/repo/http.bzl:336:31: in <toplevel>
ERROR: /home/emcp/Dev/git/grpc/grpc/BUILD:1489:16: //:activity depends on @local_config_cc//:cc-compiler-k8 in repository @local_config_cc which failed to fetch. no such package '@local_config_cc//': 
Auto-Configuration Error: Cannot find gcc or CC (clang); either correct your path or set the CC environment variable
ERROR: Analysis of target '//:activity' failed; build aborted: Analysis failed
INFO: Elapsed time: 0.517s
INFO: 0 processes.
FAILED: Build did NOT complete successfully (0 packages loaded, 0 targets configured)
```

Comment: Do you have anything in your `.bazerlc` along the lines of `--action_env=PATH`

Comment: Also have you tried, `bazel shutdown && bazel build //...`?

Answer (score -1):

As mentioned [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/23719), a temporary workaround is changing the cc toolchain from `local` to `local_linux` in `(your home)/.cache/bazel/bazel(your name)/(your hash)/external/local_config_cc/BUILD`.

Comment: Kowsalya Rupineni, a link to a solution is welcome, but please ensure your answer is useful without it: [add context around the link](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259) so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it is there, then quote the most relevant part of the page you are linking to in case the target page is unavailable. [Answers that are little more than a link may be deleted.](/help/deleted-answers)